# How to pass char** in python ctype and once it is modified in 'C++' code how do i access it

Tags: python

I'm trying to access a c++ function from python using ctypes

```
int func(void**, char**policy_names) {

   // 1.allocate memory to policy_names
   // 2.fill policy_names with policy names ex: policy_names[0] ="hi" policy_names[1]="bye"

        return 0; 
  }
```

memory allocation happens in c++ func mentioned above and the policy_name is filled with list of strings .

python code:

```
policy_list = POINTER(c_char)()

Handle = c_void_p()

Getpolicy = lib.func()

func.argtypes = [c_void_p, POINTER(POINTER(c_char))]

x = GetPolicy(Handle, policy_list)
```

---

Questions I have is

1. Is it the right way of passing `char** args` using ctypes ??
2. once the c++ function allocates , fills the `policy_names` how do i access it back in python??

Answer (score 0):

I some how fixed it after some research

it should be the following way:

I'm trying to access a c++ function from python using ctypes

python code:

policy_list = POINTER(c_char_p)()

Handle = c_void_p()

Getpolicy = lib.func()

x = GetPolicy(Handle, policy_list)

---

2. how to access it is

policy_list[0], .....